React Asynchronous states Problem - state in Context set to true but remains false in the component (React authentication with Context and API call)
I have a problem with asynchronous states on React
I use context to determine whether the admin is authenticated and has the right to access a page with a state called isAuth
interface UserContext {
    setToken: (token:string) => void;
    getToken: () => string|null;
    logout: () => void;
    setIsAuth: (value:boolean) => void;
    isAuth: boolean;
}

const initialState: UserContext = {
    setToken: () => {}, 
    getToken: () => null,
    logout: () => {},
    setIsAuth: () => {},
    isAuth: false,
}

const UserContext = createContext<UserContext>(initialState)

export function UserContextProvider ({children}:{children:React.ReactNode}){
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);

    console.log("isAuth in UserContextProvider",isAuth);

    const setToken = (token:string) => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    }

    const getToken = () => {
        return window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    const logout = () => {
        //redirect("/login")
        window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }


    return <UserContext.Provider value={{setToken, getToken, logout, setIsAuth, isAuth }}>
        {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
}

export const useUserContext = () => {
    return useContext(UserContext)
}

main.ts
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <UserContextProvider>
      <App />
    </UserContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

In App, I make an API call to check if the admin is authenticated, and I set isAuth to response.code === 200 (if authenticated, the response is 200). In this case, the admin is authenticated so the response is 200 and isAuth is set to true
function App() {
  const {setIsAuth,getToken} = useUserContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = getToken();

    fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL+"/isAuth", {
      headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("response App",response);
        setIsAuth(response.code === 200);
    })
    
  }, [location.pathname])

In the ProjectTable component (the admin page that displays projects), I need to check if he is authenticated, and if not, redirect to /login
I made a log of isAuth
export function ProjectTable({projects}:{projects:Project[]}){
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const {isAuth} = useUserContext();
    const navigateTo = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        
        console.log("isAuth in useEffect ProjectTable",isAuth);

        // if (!isAuth){
        //     navigateTo("/login");
        // }

    }, [])

Here is the console output when I am on the admin page ProjectTable, which displays the projects

isAuth in UserContextProvider is false and isAuth in ProjectTable is false.
Then I make the API call and set isAuth to true.
isAuth in UserContextProvider is set to true, but not in ProjectTable. I don't see the log indicating that isAuth is true; I only see the old log showing it as false before isAuth in UserContextProvider becomes true.
So, if I uncomment if (!isAuth), I am redirected to /login even though I shouldn't be because I am authenticated

You should print isAuth in the function component. Otherwise, the value of isAuth is the stale value when the component mounted.
export function ProjectTable({projects}:{projects:Project[]}){
  const {isAuth} = useUserContext();

  console.log("isAuth in useEffect ProjectTable",isAuth)
}

Or, add it to the dependency list of useEffect hook
export function ProjectTable({projects}:{projects:Project[]}){
  const {isAuth} = useUserContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("isAuth in useEffect ProjectTable",isAuth)
  }, [isAuth]);
}


With isAuth printed in the function component and in the useEffect dependency, isAuth becomes true. But if I check that isAuth is true, I am still redirected because at the beginning isAuth is false

With isAuth printed in the function component :
export function ProjectTable({projects}:{projects:Project[]}){
    const {isAuth} = useUserContext();
    const navigateTo = useNavigate();

    console.log("isAuth in function ProjectTable",isAuth);

    // if (!isAuth){
    //     navigateTo("/login");
    // }


If I uncomment
if (!isAuth){
     navigateTo("/login");
}

I am redirected to /login because at the beginning isAuth is false
With isAuth in the useEffect dependency :
export function ProjectTable({projects}:{projects:Project[]}){
    const {isAuth} = useUserContext();
    const navigateTo = useNavigate();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
        console.log("isAuth in useEffect ProjectTable",isAuth);

        // if (!isAuth){
        //     navigateTo("/login");
        // }

    }, [isAuth])


If I uncomment
if (!isAuth){
     navigateTo("/login");
}

I am redirected to /login because at the beginning isAuth is false
